Closure of $C([0,1]^2)$ via weak*-topology
Let $C([0,1]^2)$ denote the set of continuous functions on $[0,1]^2$. Let $L^1([0,1]^2)$ be the set of all Lebesgue integrable functions on $[0,1]^2$.
The dual space of $C([0,1]^2)$, denoted by $C^*([0,1]^2)$, consists of all bounded, linear functionals that map from $C([0,1]^2)$ to $\mathbb{R}$. Specifically,
$$C^*([0,1]^2) = \left\{ \varphi: C([0,1]^2) \to \mathbb{R} \mid \varphi \text{ is linear and continuous} \right\}.$$
The norm of any $\varphi \in C^*([0,1]^2)$ is given by the weak* norm:
$$\lVert \varphi \rVert_* = \sup_{\lVert f \rVert_C \leq 1} |\varphi(f)|.$$
We have $C\subseteq L_1\subseteq C^*$.
Question Does the closure of $C([0,1]^2)$ be $L_1([0,1]^2)$ (or a subset of $L_1([0,1]^2)$) when considering topology $\lVert \cdot \rVert_*$?

"Weak* norm" is a nonsense; you probably mean "dual norm"

Besides, the questions in the title and in the text are different

Do you have a response to the answers below?

yes, thanks for your two kind answers and I voted both of your answers up!

If you are satisfied with the answers then you should accept one of them, so that your question does not show up in the list of "unresolved" questions

@YemonChoi Sorry for unfamilar of this rule.

Let's look more closely at the inclusions you wrote. The first, $C\subset L^1$, is dense w.r.to the $L^1$-norm  (for this, it is sufficient to note that the $\|\cdot\|_1$-closure of $C$ contains the characteristic functions of rectangles $[a,b]\times[c,d]$, which is clear, hence contains all characteristic functions of measurable sets, hence all integrable simple functions, hence the whole $L^1$).
The other inclusion, $L^1\subset C^*$, is isometric just because for every $f\in L^1$ $$\|f\|_{C^*}:= \sup_{g\in C, \|g\|_C\le 1}\int fg=\|f\|_1,$$
which follows from the preceding one, since you can approximate $\text{sgn}  f$ in $L^1$ by a sequence $(g_k)_k$ in the unit ball of $C$. Being isometric, the inclusion $L^1\subset C^*$ is closed, because $L^1$ is complete.
But then the closure of any  set $S\subset L^1$ into $C^*$ w.r.to the $\|\cdot\|_{C^*}$ norm is  exactly the same as its closure in $L^1$ w.r.to the $\|\cdot\|_{L^1}$-norm; in particular the $\|\cdot\|_{C^*}$-closure of $C$ in $C^*$ is $L^1$.
As to the question in the title: The weak* closure of $C$ as a subset of $C^*$ is $C^*$: recall that a linear subspace $V$ of a dual $X^*$ is weak* dense iff its pre-annihilator $V_\perp:=\{x\in X: \forall f\in V\,  \langle f,x\rangle=0\}$ is $(0)$, which is of course the case here.

By the Riesz–Markov theorem, your $C^*$ is the space of all finite signed Borel measures on $Q:=[0,1]^2$ endowed with the total variation norm $\|\cdot\|$, which is the same as your dual norm $\|\cdot\|_C$.
Let now $(f_n)$ be a sequence of functions in $L_1$ such that the corresponding measures converge to a signed measure $\mu\in C^*$ wrt the total variation norm $\|\cdot\|$, that is,
$$d_n:=\int_Q|f_n(x)\,dx-\mu(dx)|\to0. \tag{1}\label{1}$$
Suppose for a second that the singular (wrt to the Lebesgue measure) component (say $\nu$) of $\mu$ is
nonzero, so that $\mu(dx)=f(x)\,dx+\nu(dx)$ for some $f\in L_1$, and for some Borel subset $B$ of $Q$ of Lebesgue measure $0$ we have $c:=|\nu|(B)>0$. Then $d_n\ge c>0$ for all $n$, which contradicts \eqref{1}. So, $\nu=0$ and $\mu(dx)=f(x)\,dx$.
Thus, indeed the closure of $C$ is a subset of $L_1$.
On the other hand, the restriction of the total variation norm $\|\cdot\|$ to $L_1$ is the $L_1$-norm. Also, $C$ is dense in $L_1$ wrt to the $L_1$-norm.
Thus, the closure of $C$ is $L_1$.
